# PHP XML Last Array to Int

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML file (filename.xml) constantly being added to:

```
<archive>
  <unit id="14044669018">
    <data>Testing #1</data>
    <link/>
    <img/>
    <tpimg/>
    <odate>14:04:46 69 018</odate>
    <gdate>2018-05-27 14:04:46</gdate>
  </unit>
  <unit id="14045769018">
    <data>Testing #2 with link</data>
    <link>https://website.com/user_xml/index.php</link>
    <img/>
    <tpimg/>
    <odate>14:04:57 69 018</odate>
    <gdate>2018-05-27 14:04:57</gdate>
  </unit>
  <unit id="14051169018">
    <data>Testing #3 with img link</data>
    <link/>
    <img/>
    <tpimg>https://website.com/ex.jpg</tpimg>
    <odate>14:05:11 69 018</odate>
    <gdate>2018-05-27 14:05:11</gdate>
  </unit>
</archive>
```

I want to first turn the last `unit` in to an array then in to individual int so they can be echoed in different areas.

Have tried 7 DOM and xpath examples including this one I thought would work:

```
$filename = 'filename.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$last = $xml->xpath('/archive/unit[last()]'); 
$last = $last[0]; // <data> (example)
echo $last;
```

But even with some tweaking I am getting nowhere. Any directional help is appreciated.

Comment: @zx485 Did not change the above code results :(

Comment: The `unit` element nodes do not have text content, casting them to string will turn them into an empty string. Try `var_dump($last)` or  `echo $last->asXml();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below method

first convert it from XML to array then just get last element

```
$object = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json  = json_encode($object);
$final_array = json_decode($json, true);
$last = end($final_array ['unit']);
```

output as below:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14051169018
        )

    [data] => Testing #3 with img link
    [link] => Array
        (
        )

    [img] => Array
        (
        )

    [tpimg] => https://website.com/ex.jpg
    [odate] => 14:05:11 69 018
    [gdate] => 2018-05-27 14:05:11
)
```

Comment: $last in your code then needs $last = $last[0] then echo or else? I get no results using your code.

Comment: print $final_array before $last line, so, you got the idea about array

Comment: $xml_array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), 1);  $last = end($xml_array['unit']); print_r($last); works. A partial thanks!

Comment: Thats what I thought but swear to god, your version did not work for me, but mine did. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯